# Adding an exisiting method to interface

Tags: java, android

I'm again stuck with Kilibolt Tutorial, but now it's another case.
I need to draw polygons, but there is no such method in android. So I googled this and found what I need. To draw a polygon I need method drawPath(Path path, Paint paint). I import android.graphics.Canvas everywhere i need and then add this method to the interface "Graphics"(as in Kilobolt Tutorial). After that "AndroidGraphics" class says, that there are unimplemented methods to add and I add it. And I get this.

```
@Override
    public void drawPath(Path path, Paint paint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Does that mean, that such needed method works?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all...

It just means that you have to implement it.

Your IDE will automatically generate a method for you which at least makes the code compile.

Since your method "returns void", well, the "auto-generated method stub" will do nothing.

If it had returned an int, the generated stub would probably have returned 0. If any Object or subclass, `null`; etc etc.

It is just a reminder that you *do* have to provide an implementation...

It is just a comment; if you wish you can edit your IDE preferences and replace that with:

```
// TODO need an implementation here
```

or something.

---

EDIT: in fact this is a bug in the IDE; it is not a method implemented from an interface but a method overriden from a superclass; yet the template engine didn't generate a call to `super`...

Comment: But there is such a method in Canvas - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path, android.graphics.Paint)

I don't really know what happens here and I can't find the source code for this method

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the IDE you are using; if you selected to override the method, it should have at least generated a call to the super method but it didn't. You should at least call `super.drawPath(path, paint);`.

Comment: "The method drawPath(Path, Paint) is undefined for the type Object".
That's what it says when i added this in method